# Sorting Object of Objects using Object.values()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to sort an `object` of objects using `Object.values()`, `sort()` and `map()` into pages based on a nested value. It's works perfect in FF, but Chrome for some reason returns pages full of unsorted items.

Example structure of `list`:

```
{
    1: {
        id: 1,
        rank: 10,
        name: "foo"
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        rank: 24,
        name: "bar"
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        rank: 11,
        name: "baz"
    },
    ...
}
```

Example:

```js
const out = document.getElementById("out");
const sortBy = "rank";
const perPage = 10;
let list = {};

for (let i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
  list[i] = {
    id: i,
    rank: rand(10, 200),
    name: generateName(rand(6, 12))
  }
}

const values = Object.values(list);
const pages = values.sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortBy === "rank") {
      return a.rank < b.rank;
    } else if (sortBy === "name") {
      return a.name > b.name;
    }
  })
  .map((item, i) => {
    return i % perPage === 0 ? values.slice(i, i + perPage) : null;
  }).filter(page => page);

for (const page of pages) {
  for (const item of page) {
    out.value += `${item.rank}\n`;
  }
}













// HELPERS
function rand(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function generateName(length) {
  let result = '';
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="out" cols="60" rows="30"></textarea>
```

[Demo Pen](https://codepen.io/Mobius1/pen/eYzmNOK?editors=0010)

Comment: Your sort comparator function is incorrect. The comparator is supposed to return a numeric value: negative, if `a` goes before `b`; positive, if `a` goes after `b`; and zero if they are equal (in terms of the sort criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Pointy. So the answer should be like this.

```js
const pages = values.sort((a, b) => a.rank < b.rank ? 1 : -1)
```